# How to auto reference to other post in Sanity.io?

Tags: sanity

i recently tried sanity.io CMS to manage content on my personal blog. however i'm facing a little difficulty to find part in the documentation about 'auto referencing' (this just my term). i want for each my blog post to have data of next and previous post, so i can create button at the bottom to navigate to next or previous blog post. how can i achieve it? thankss

Answer (score 3):

To me, this is a job for a query rather than a reference.

There is no way to "auto-reference" something the way you are describing however there are a few ways you can achieve your effect:

#### 1. Manually link them

#### 2. Create a custom input field that queries for your previous/next posts. More on custom input components here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/custom-input-widgets

#### 3. Use a GROQ query to get all posts and the find the ones you need (in JS):

```
const posts = await Sanity.fetch(`*[_type == 'post']`);

const currentPostIndex = posts.findIndex(post => post.id === currentPost.id);
const previousPost = posts[currentPostIndex - 1];
const nextPost = posts[currentPostIndex + 1];
```

#### 4. Add date queries to get the adjacent posts with GROQ (in JS):

```
const posts = await Sanity.fetch(`*[_type == 'post' && _id == '${currentPost.id}' ][0] {
  'currentPost': {
    ...
  },
  'previousPost': *[_type == 'post' && _createdAt < ^._createdAt][0],
  'nextPost': *[_type == 'post' && _createdAt > ^._createdAt] | order(_createdAt asc)[0]
}`);

const currentPostIndex = posts.findIndex(post => post.id === currentPost.id);
const previousPost = posts[currentPostIndex - 1];
const nextPost = posts[currentPostIndex + 1];
```

More info on GROQ `https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet`